# How to extract value from html via BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have parsed my string via BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def otoMoto(link):
    URL = link
    page = requests.get(URL).content

    bs = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    for offer in bs.find_all('div', class_= "offer-item__content ds-details-container"):

        # print(offer)
        # print("znacznik")
        linkOtoMoto = offer.find('a', class_="offer-title__link").get('href')
        # title = offer.find("a")
        titleOtoMoto = offer.find('a', class_="offer-title__link").get('title')
        rokProdukcji = offer.find('li', class_="ds-param").get_text().strip()
        rokPrzebPojemPali = offer.find_all('li',class_="ds-param")
        print(linkOtoMoto+" "+titleOtoMoto+" "+rokProdukcji)
        print(rokPrzebPojemPali)
        break

URL = "https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/bmw/seria-3/od-2016/?search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Afrom%5D=50000&search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Ato%5D=65000&search%5Bfilter_float_year%3Ato%5D=2016&search%5Bfilter_float_mileage%3Ato%5D=100000&search%5Bfilter_enum_financial_option%5D=1&search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Adesc&search%5Bbrand_program_id%5D%5B0%5D=&search%5Bcountry%5D="

otoMoto(URL)
```

Result:

```
https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/bmw-seria-3-x-drive-nowe-opony-ID6Dr4JE.html#d51bf88c70 BMW Seria 3 2016
[<li class="ds-param" data-code="year">
<span>2016 </span>
</li>, <li class="ds-param" data-code="mileage">
<span>50 000 km</span>
</li>, <li class="ds-param" data-code="engine_capacity">
<span>1 998 cm3</span>
</li>, <li class="ds-param" data-code="fuel_type">
<span>Benzyna</span>
</li>]
```

So I can extract single strings, but if I see this same class

```
class="ds-param"
```

I can't assigne, for example, production date to variable. Please let me know if you have any ideas :).

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the docs:

Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:

```
data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a dictionary and passing the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs argument:

```
data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
# [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
```

so you could do something like
`data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-code": "year" })[0]. get_text()`